# How to load ListView after AsyncTask finishes?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I am using an `AsyncTask` to get the data and then loading it into a `ListView`. My code is :

```
AsyncTaskTwitterFeeds asyncTaskTwitterFeeds = new AsyncTaskTwitterFeeds(TwitterFeedsActivity.this);
    asyncTaskTwitterFeeds.execute("");
    loadList();
```

In the above code, once `AsyncTask` is executed, the flow, comes to `loadlist()` method and the program crashes. The reason I found was that the array which is used in the `Adapter` is still being populated. I want to know that how I can hold once `AsyncTask` is executed and only when its completed then flow should go to `loadlist()` method. Here is the `LogCat` error:

```
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cubix.twitterfeed/com.cubix.twitterfeed.TwitterFeedsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:47)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:169)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:125)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.cubix.twitterfeed.TwitterAdapter.<init>(TwitterAdapter.java:17)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.cubix.twitterfeed.TwitterFeedsActivity.loadList(TwitterFeedsActivity.java:48)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.cubix.twitterfeed.TwitterFeedsActivity.onCreate(TwitterFeedsActivity.java:30)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
02-25 18:50:25.879: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has a method [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) that executes on the main UI thread **after** the `AsyncTask` has finished its job in the method `doInBackground()`. You could use that method to populate the list if `loadList()` is called to populate the list with the results from the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: yes that is how I manage to do it, but I am trying to find out way to do it in main activity not in onPostExecute().